# How do I traverse the selector from select tag to button tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this HTML code below. I want to change the attribute of the button using a dropdown menu. I have a lot of this set in a page so selector by ID is not an option. (I already thought of having ID individually but that will be my last resort.)

```js
$('.shirtSize').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent().children("button").attr("data-item-custom1-value", this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item-content">
  <span>
         <select class="shirtSize">
           <option>S</option>
           <option>M</option>
           <option>L</option>
           <option>XL</option>
         </select>
       </span>
  <span>
         <select class="shirtColor">
           <option>White</option>
           <option>Blue</option>
         </select>
       </span>
  <span>
         <button class="mini-btn">Add To Cart</button>
       </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest("div").find("button");` or `$(this).parent().next().find("button")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent of the `select` is the `span`. The `button` is not a child of the `span`.

You need to go all the way up to the `div`, then search for the button within that.

```js
$('.shirtSize').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest("div.product-item-content").find("button").attr("data-item-custom1-value", this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item-content">
  <span>
     <select class="shirtSize">
       <option>S</option>
       <option>M</option>
       <option>L</option>
       <option>XL</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  <span>
     <select class="shirtColor">
       <option>White</option>
       <option>Blue</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  <span>
     <button class="mini-btn">Add To Cart</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Barmar's solution seems to change the button data attribute only the first time and will also only assign the data of the *first* select element. The following snippet will collect *both* select values and assign them (repeatedly) to the button element's data attribute:

```js
$(document.body).on('change',"select", function() {
  let p=$(this).closest("div.product-item-content");
  $("button",p).data("item-custom1-value",$("select",p).get().map(s=>s.value).join("-"));
  console.log($("button",p).data("item-custom1-value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item-content">
  <span>
     <select class="shirtSize">
       <option>S</option>
       <option>M</option>
       <option>L</option>
       <option>XL</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  <span>
     <select class="shirtColor">
       <option>White</option>
       <option>Blue</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  <span>
     <button class="mini-btn">Add To Cart</button>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="product-item-content">
  <span>
     <select class="shirtSize">
       <option>A</option>
       <option>B</option>
       <option>C</option>
       <option>DL</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  <span>
     <select class="shirtColor">
       <option>Red</option>
       <option>Green</option>
       <option>Black</option>
       <option>White</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  <span>
     <button class="mini-btn">Add To Cart</button>
   </span>
</div>
```